# Convert from '_io.BytesIO' to a bytes-like object in python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, zlib, bytesio

I am using this function to uncompress the body of a HTTP response if it is compressed with gzip, compress or deflate.

```
def uncompress_body(self, compression_type, body):
    if compression_type == 'gzip' or compression_type == 'compress':
        return zlib.decompress(body)
    elif compression_type == 'deflate':
        compressor = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
        compressed = compressor.compress(body)
        compressed += compressor.flush()
        return base64.b64encode(compressed)

    return body
```

However python throws this error message.

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'
```

on this line:

```
return zlib.decompress(body)
```

Essentially, how do I convert from '_io.BytesIO' to a bytes-like object?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

It's a file-like object.  Read them:

```
>>> b = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
>>> b.read()
b'hello'
```

If the data coming in from `body` is too large to read into memory, you'll want to refactor your code and use [`zlib.decompressobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompressobj) instead of `zlib.decompress`.

Comment: When you overthink a basic solution :D

Answer (score 60):

In case you write into the object first, make sure to reset the stream before reading:

```
>>> b = io.BytesIO()
>>> image = PIL.Image.open(path_to_image)
>>> image.save(b, format='PNG')
>>> b.seek(0)
>>> b.read()
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x06\xcf\x00\x00\x03W\x08\x02\x00'
```

or directly get the data with `getvalue`

```
>>> b.getvalue()
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x06\xcf\x00\x00\x03W\x08\x02\x00'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
b = io.BytesIO()
image = PIL.Image.open(path_to_image) # ie 'image.png'
image.save(b, format='PNG')
b.getbuffer().tobytes() # b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00 ...
```

Comment: Please add context as to *why* this is an answer.

Comment: One upside to this answer is that you don't need to reset the stream with `b.seek` to get the full bytes that were written to it.

Comment: `.getbuffer().tobytes()` can be shorted to simply `.getvalue()`

Answer (score 2):

I know its late for the answer but if anyone finds into same issue then the below code snippet might be useful.

```py
from io import BytesIO


data = BytesIO(b'Some data')

bytes_data = data.getvalue()

print(bytes_data, type(bytes_data)
```

Output

```bash
b'Some data' <class 'bytes'>
```