# How to create text file in Google Cloud Storage without saving it locally?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know how to upload a string saved to a text file to Google Cloud Storage: using the `upload_blob` function below ([source](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python)):

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

I can create a file stored on local disk:

```
!touch localfile
!echo "contents of my file" > localfile
!cat localfile  # outputs: contents of my file
```

Upload this file to Google Cloud Storage:

```
upload_blob('my-project','localfile','gcsfile')
```

It is indeed uploaded:

[image]

**How can I create `gcsfile` in Google Cloud Storage containing the string `contents of my file`, without saving it first?**

---

I tried:

```
import io

output = io.BytesIO()
output.write(b'First line.\n')

upload_blob('adventdalen-003',output,'out')
```

Doesn't work, I get:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

---

Similar but different threads:

- [How do I upload a base64 encoded image (string) directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879012/how-do-i-upload-a-base64-encoded-image-string-directly-to-a-google-cloud-stora)
- [Upload JSON string to Google Cloud Storage without a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667403/upload-json-string-to-google-cloud-storage-without-a-file)

Neither of these are in Python.

Comment: The source says it wants a file. Why can't you create a local, temporary file?

Comment: I would like to do this from Google Cloud Functions, and I prefer not messing about with files there.

Comment: If you convert the BytesIO into an actual bytes object, like the error says it expects, then what error do you get?

Comment: Also, you seem to be ignoring the `upload_blob_from_memory` function... Why?

Comment: First question: if I replace `output` with `output.read()`, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54137810/8565438), I get `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. Second question: because I didn't know about it, but thanks! I think this will solve my problem.

Comment: Consult the documentation to review the methods available. https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html For example **blob.upload_from_string()** Upload contents of this blob from the provided string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using @johnhanley's suggestions this is the code to implement blob.upload_from_string():

```
from google.cloud import storage

def write_to_blob(bucket_name,file_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    blob.upload_from_string("written in python")

write_to_blob(bucket_name="test-bucket",file_name="from_string.txt")
```

Saved in Google Cloud Storage:

[image]

Inside `from_string.txt`:

[image]